# Does it matter, and if so, how should "dAMP" (meaning "deoxyadenosine monophosphate") be pronounced?

Tags: nomenclature, dna-rna

When an expert says "dAMP" (meaning "deoxyadenosine monophosphate") is it pronounced "dee ay em pee", "lowercase dee ay em pee", "damp", "dee amp", or something else (and does it matter)?

Comment: Does it matter? Laser is also an acronym but we pronounce it as a word instead of individual letters.

Comment: @nilayghosh Good point. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162571/why-is-deoxyadenosine-monophosphate-called-damp-and-not-damp?rq=1

Comment: Pronounce it as dee-ay-em-pee. That sounds the most natural. "damp" means something else, so you can't use it.

Comment: @SRMaiti The fact that DAMP means something already makes it easier to learn. A sort of mnemonic in effect. Not sure that in chemistry you can't pronounce dAMP as "damp" because the latter means something else - would you care to expand on that?

Comment: Of course it matters: wrongly pronounced, people either don't understand or immediately identify the speaker as a beginner. Otoh of course it doesn't matter: you'll find out quickly when you start talking to the pros.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh Well, generally people avoid words that mean something else already. For example, if you mix tea and coffee, it is called "cofftea", not "toffee" because there is already a thing called toffee! Since people prononunce AMP as ay-em-pee, it's makes sense to pronounce the d in front of it. Besides how would you pronounce dGMP? It can't be pronounced in go anyway, so you are forced to pronounce each letter separately.

Comment: @SRMaiti I'd pronounce "dGMP" as "dee jee em pee". But that doesn't mean I can't pronounce "dAMP" as "damp" or "dee amp".

Comment: @NilayGhosh When you write: "Laser is also an acronym **but** [emphasis mine] we pronounce it as a word instead of individual letters", that's essentially saying: "*even though* it's an acronym, we still pronounce it as a word."  In fact, laser is an acronym *precisely because* we pronounce it as a word.  That's what acronym means:  An abbreviation pronounced as a word.  So your comment would have been better phrased as: "Laser is considered an acronym *because* we pronounce it as a word, rather than as individual letters".

Comment: @theorist I agree I could have phrased it that way but it's not applicable for all cases. Take an acronym that cannot be  pronounced as a word e.g. RDX then we have to pronounce as individual letters.

Comment: @NilayGhosh  I'm afraid that's not correct.  Abbreviations that aren't pronounced as words, like "RDX" "CPU", or "HIV" are *not* acronyms.  That's what I've been trying to explain.  Instead, they're *initialisms*.  Quoting from my Mac's dictionary:  "**Acronym**. An abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA)." "**Initialism**.  An abbreviation consisting of initial letters pronounced separately (e.g., CPU)."  For more info., see: https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/65823/Acronyms-Initialisms-and-Abbreviations

Comment: I spent years of my life - and have the publications to show for it - studying how motor proteins work. Thus, a good portion of my working vocabulary at the time was comprised of the word "MgATP," which all parties pronounced "em gee ay tee pee." I hereby cast my vote for "dee ay em pee" in the case we're talking about here.